# How to SetEnv for an Alias

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd, alias, environment-variables

I have several Aliasses configured in apache configuration.
I would like to set an environmental variables for each of them. How?

I have this

```
/alias1 /mapped/to/a/path
/alias2 /mapped/to/a/path
/alias3 /mapped/to/a/path
/alias4 /mapped/to/a/path
/alias5 /mapped/to/a/path
```

what I want is to forward an environmental variable, for each alias

something like

```
/alias1 /mapped/to/a/path AND SetEnv VAR=a
/alias2 /mapped/to/a/path AND SetEnv VAR=b
/alias3 /mapped/to/a/path AND SetEnv VAR=c
/alias4 /mapped/to/a/path AND SetEnv VAR=d
/alias5 /mapped/to/a/path AND SetEnv VAR=e
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?  To have an env set based on which alias a request is getting sent to, maybe?

Comment: Please clarify what do you expect from Apache?

Comment: @ShaneMadden updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this should do it:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias1 VAR=a
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias2 VAR=b
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias3 VAR=c
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias4 VAR=d
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias5 VAR=e
```

If you need more flexibility on matching or conditions for some reason, you could also use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/alias1 - [E=VAR:a]
RewriteRule ^/alias2 - [E=VAR:b]
RewriteRule ^/alias3 - [E=VAR:c]
RewriteRule ^/alias4 - [E=VAR:d]
RewriteRule ^/alias5 - [E=VAR:e]
```

For domain like alias the answer is:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Comment: The rewrite rule, how can be used, to rewrite to some other directory, that is outside of the httdocs?

Comment: @Pentium10 These rewrite rules are just setting environment variables, not changing directories.  That's what your `Alias` directives are for - though mod_rewrite can certainly do that job as well if you need it to.